# What jQuery script works for adding colornotification boxes?

Tags: sharepoint, colors, notifications, enterprise-library, document

I am trying to implement an alert button in a SharePoint document library that will provide a color box next to folders when data has been uploaded. What jQuery script would best meet this application?

Comment: Which scripts have you tried? Show some code! Otherwise try superuser.com